# Tooltip is not coming for a control

Tags: c++, mfc

One of my application is ported from windows Xp to WIN7. For this application tool tip control is not working in win7 while it is working for XP.

Code logic:

> We are setting tooltip in a const string. `aToolTipText =anImageTypeStr;`
>   and passing in a function `SetToolTipText(LPCTSTR tooltiptext, long Id)` which is calling `ActivateToolTipText(int Id, bool activateFlag)` which is actually handling Tooltip based on id.

```
bool ActivateToolTipText(int Id, bool activateFlag)
{

CSA_TRY
{   
    // struct specifying info about tool in ToolTip control
    TOOLINFO ti;
    unsigned int uid = Id;       // for ti initialization

    LPTSTR lptstr = (LPTSTR)(LPCTSTR)m_strToolTipText[Id]; 

    // CREATE A TOOLTIP WINDOW 
    if(activateFlag)
    {
        m_ToolTipHWND[Id] = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST,
            TOOLTIPS_CLASS,
            NULL,
            WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP,        
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            m_hWnd,
            NULL,
            0, 
            NULL
            );
    }

    // INITIALIZE MEMBERS OF THE TOOLINFO STRUCTURE 
    ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO);
    ti.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS ;
    ti.hwnd = m_hWnd;
    ti.hinst = 0;
    ti.uId = uid;
    ti.lpszText = lptstr;  
    // ToolTip control will cover the rect of Id
    CRect rect_out;
    GetIdArea(Id, &rect_out);
    ti.rect = rect_out;

    if( activateFlag )

        ::SendMessage(m_ToolTipHWND[Id], TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFO)&ti);

    }
    else
    {
        ::SendMessage(m_ToolTipHWND[Id], TTM_DELTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFO) &ti);
    }


    return TRUE;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you run your code in a debugger? That might reveal the problem. Just step through it statement by statement and see if all your IDs and pointers are initialized correctly. Most likely the problem is not in the code you have shown, but in some other part of your program that might not be directly related to the tooltip facility.

Comment: I have debugged the code and and tooltip string and id id setting correct in tooltip structure.
 Further i have noticed using spy++ that after mouse moveTTM_RELAYEVENT is not bieng called by OLE. why it not coming in windows 7 while same code is working for XP. please suggest any workaround or root cause of this problem.

Comment: I got the solution:

changes ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO); to ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO) - 4;

Comment: It's nice that you found the problem, or at least believe so. From what I see in the documentation cbSize should contain the size of the entire structure, so the former version was correct. Are you sure that your fix did the trick, or was it something else you changed at the same time?

Comment: The problem is with common controls version 6.
for xp+, the header file CommCtrl.h assume we will use comctl version 6, but if we dont  enable it explictly with manifest file, we'll still use the old comctl version 5.x.  problem starts here, the size of TOOLINFO of version 5.x is different to version 6.x.

So if you need to use comctl version 5 under windows xp+, you should init TOOLINFO with follwing code,

TOOLINFO ti;
ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO) - 4;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with common controls version 6. for xp+, the header file CommCtrl.h assume we will use comctl version 6, but if we dont enable it explictly with manifest file, we'll still use the old comctl version 5.x. problem starts here, the size of TOOLINFO of version 5.x is different to version 6.x. So if you need to use comctl version 5 under windows xp+, you should init TOOLINFO with follwing code, TOOLINFO ti; ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO) - 4;